# How do I have buttons in an embed like the picture below in discord.py?

Tags: discord, discord.py

[image: MEE6's levels button embed]

Okay how do I have buttons in the embed like the picture above. Is it both available in discord.js and discord.py? I have heard that this is the alpha version of Discord.py, but how do I install the alpha version?

Comment: Soooo… do you want how to do it for only discord.py, only discord.js, or both?

Answer (score 2):

You would need to install the alpha version from the master branch using:

```
pip install -U git+https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py
```

Here is an example: keep in mind this is not the best method to make a `view`

```py
@bot.command()
async def test_button(ctx)
    message = await ctx.send("Reference this message")

    # Establish an instance of the discord.ui.View class
    view = discord.ui.View()
    view.add_item(item=discord.ui.Button(style=discord.ButtonStyle.link,
                                         label="Go to message",
                                         url=message.jump_url
                                         )
                  )

    await ctx.send("Test of button", view=view)
```

Docs from master:
[`discord.Button`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/master/api.html?highlight=button#discord.Button)